# How to remove Out of Stock products only from homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock, home-page

I am having the Magento website. I want to remove the Out of Stock products from  New Books Arrived tab of homepage, but it should be visible on categories of my website. I just want to remove it only from homepage, else it should be visible on other pages. For better understanding i am attaching the screenshot of my homepage. I had tried to copy the file New.php to local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/New.php & used below code, but still problem did not solved

New.php

```
<?php
/**
* New products widget
*
* @category Mage
* @package Mage_Catalog
* @author Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
*/
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    /**
     * Display products type
     */
    const DISPLAY_TYPE_ALL_PRODUCTS = 'all_products';
    const DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS = 'new_products';

    /**
     * Default value whether show pager or not
     */
    const DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER = false;

    /**
     * Default value for products per page
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 5;

    /**
     * Name of request parameter for page number value
     */
    const PAGE_VAR_NAME = 'np';

    /**
     * Instance of pager block
     *
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_Html_Pager
     */
    protected $_pager;

    /**
     * Default product amount per row
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_defaultColumnCount = 5;

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache and template settings
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addPriceBlockType('bundle', 'bundle/catalog_product_price', 'bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Product collection initialize process
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection|Object|Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        switch ($this->getDisplayType()) {
            case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_NEW_PRODUCTS:
                $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
                break;
            default:
                $collection = $this->_getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection();
                break;
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection for recent product list
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection|Object|Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    protected function _getRecentlyAddedProductsCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        if (Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
        }

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1);
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Get key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getCacheKeyInfo(), array(
            $this->getDisplayType(),
            $this->getProductsPerPage(),
            intval($this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PAGE_VAR_NAME))
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve display type for products
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDisplayType()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('display_type')) {
            $this->setData('display_type', self::DISPLAY_TYPE_ALL_PRODUCTS);
        }
        return $this->getData('display_type');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how much products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('products_count')) {
            return parent::getProductsCount();
        }
        return $this->getData('products_count');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how much products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsPerPage()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('products_per_page')) {
            $this->setData('products_per_page', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE);
        }
        return $this->getData('products_per_page');
    }

    /**
     * Return flag whether pager need to be shown or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showPager()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('show_pager')) {
            $this->setData('show_pager', self::DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER);
        }
        return (bool)$this->getData('show_pager');
    }

    /**
     * Render pagination HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        if ($this->showPager()) {
            if (!$this->_pager) {
                $this->_pager = $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('catalog/product_widget_html_pager', 'widget.new.product.list.pager');

                $this->_pager->setUseContainer(true)
                    ->setShowAmounts(true)
                    ->setShowPerPage(false)
                    ->setPageVarName(self::PAGE_VAR_NAME)
                    ->setLimit($this->getProductsPerPage())
                    ->setTotalLimit($this->getProductsCount())
                    ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
            }
            if ($this->_pager instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
                return $this->_pager->toHtml();
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

new_grid.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 */
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Books Arrived') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-products">
        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; ?>
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col-widget">
            <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <?php // The image size is locked at 210 for this for display purposes. CSS has it at 75% which should equate to 278px?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You can add controller condition in the list.phtml whether it is home page or category page. Check $product is out of the stock or not in $collection

Comment: How to do this. I only want to remove Out Of Stock products from homepage only not from category.

Comment: use - `$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();` get controller name in list.phtml file so you can track page name cms-index or category-page and you can check if product is sale able or not  `$_product->isSaleable()`

Comment: Can you please summerize ur answer i did not get you

Answer (score 1):

Setting Display out of stock products to No only hides them from the category list pages and the search results page. Actually This is a feature.

If you want a product not to be available at all in your store you have to mark it as disabled or set it's visibility to Not visible individually or remove its association to the websites from the websites tab on the admin product edit page.

Comment: I know all these things. Indeed I want to remove Out of Stock products from homepage only not from the entire website

Comment: then in the prepare collection Add this filter  [code]     Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status')->addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection);[/code]

Comment: @SalmanDalal - Can I have your code

Comment: you can but which code you want can you tell me the filename

Comment: If your block template is "catalog/product/new.phtml" then Add the line after <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
  <?php if($_product->isAvailable()):?> // If product is available then it will return boolean true

Comment: I did not got your code can you explain me which file I have to edit & where to add this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59492/discussion-between-salman-dalal-and-arjun-me).

Answer (score 0):

Add an **if condition** in foreach loop as below.

```
<?php
/**
 */
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Books Arrived') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-products">
        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; ?>
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col-widget">
            <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>  <!-- Saleable product's If Condition starts -->
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <?php // The image size is locked at 210 for this for display purposes. CSS has it at 75% which should equate to 278px?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?> <!-- Saleable product's If Condition ends -->
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me in the code

Comment: I have updated your code in my answer.. Check it now.

Comment: Your code does not work

Comment: Any Other solution to this @Dinesh Yadav

Comment: I have to check your code in my local magento. But I am busy right now. I'll inform you later.

Comment: Okzz no problem